# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS htaccess HTTP_REFERER redirect rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many redirect rules in my .htaccess file. All are working fine but when I tried to implement htaccess rule using `http_referer` browser is showing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` message during the redirect. Redirect is working fine.

Here is what I am trying. We have an external site
`https://www.abcd.com` in which there is a link
`https://www.xyz1.com/de/TestPass`. But it should redirect to
`https://www.xyz1.com/de/TestPass?agency=abcd` not to
`https://www.xyz1.com/de/TestPass`

I have tried as shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www.abcd.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz1.com/de/TestPass?agency=abcd[L,R=301]
```

Please help.

Thanks, Raj

Comment: does `https://www.xyz1.com/de/TestPass?agency=abcd` redirects to `abcd.com` ?

Comment: I have updated my questions ...sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the RewriteRule add

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !agency
```

That will avoid the looping.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This fixed the issue. Could you please tell me how this got fixed and why that looping was happening.

Comment: The browser was preserving the referer across redirects and so the rewrite condition still matched. The new rewrite cond declines to redirect if you've already redirected once, thus breaking the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.